# Tratamento de caracteres não salvos em variáveis com f-strings no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Para manipular caracteres não salvos em variáveis faço isso com f-strings:

```
print(f'{"String":^20}')
```

Gostaria de saber está certo, ou seria uma gambiarra pelo fato de eu definir a string nas chaves com aspas duplas, pois se eu usar aspas simples acontece um erro.

Comment: Por que você quer fazer isso? Isso está parecendo um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5210/132). Sem entender o propósito de você querer fazer isso, fica difícil avaliar se seria gambiarra ou não.

Comment: Usar aspas simples ou aspas duplas é outra coisa totalmente diferente. Se a string começa com aspas simples, então ela termina com aspas simples e aí as aspas duplas serão um caractere como outro qualquer. Se a string começa com aspas duplas, então ela termina com aspas duplas e aí as aspas simples serão um caractere como outro qualquer.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente. Comecei a pesquisar sobre F'strings, mas nunca vi alguém utilizar uma string com aspas diretamente nas chaves, por isso pergunto. Eu poderia utilizar o .format, e já vi vários exercícios que usam o .format com Python para manipular strings fora de variáveis, só nunca vi com F'strings.

Comment: Vc tem que mudar o tipo das aspas porque é assim que foi definido: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences

Comment: Entendi, obrigado @hkotsubo. Fiz a pergunta só porque não tinha visto em nenhum outro lugar isso que faço. Se quiser responder a pergunta de fato, eu a aceitarei, assim podemos fechá-la, pois já tenho minha resposta. Se não tiver problema posso remover a pergunta, mas gostaria de atribuir a resposta a você, pois me ajudou.

Comment: Bem, como já disse o Victor, sem mais contexto, é difícil responder se é gambiarra ou não... É um recurso da linguagem e pode ser usado (mas assim como todo recurso, pode ser mal usado também, e tudo depende do contexto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar *f-Strings*, você tem que decidir se logo depois do *f* vai querer usar aspas simples ou aspas duplas. Se você decidir usar aspas simples no *f*, então para escrever a *string* terá que usar aspas duplas, mas se você decidir usar aspas duplas com o *f*, então terá que usar aspas simples com o *f*. Por exemplo:

```
print(f'{"String":^20}')
```

ou

```
print(f"{'String':^20}")
```

Você pode usar tanto *f* quanto *F*.

Answer (score -2):

Está certo, pelo que eu entendi, pelo menos. O erro ao qual você se refere é porque o Python forma duplas com aspas simples ou duplas, ou seja, `f'xxx{'palavra'}'` é lido como se "xxx{" fosse uma string e "}" outra, mas "palavra" não está englobado como string. O mesmo acontece se substituirmos as aspas simples pelas duplas.