# Não consigo armazenar na variável soma os valores em float de cada comida digitada

Tags: python, tuple

> Sei fazer da maneira mais simples (o cardápio) usando só formatação, mas gostaria de saber como consigo montar o cardápio como na foto, e como uso o while e o for na construção do programa. Segue o exercício, e vou colocar no final o que eu já tentei fazer:

Exercício:

Dado a tupla abaixo, faça um programa que:

```
t1 = ('Doce', 2.3, 'Bala ', 0.15, 'Pizza ', 28.9, 'Arroz ', 4.5, 'Paçoca ', 0.5, 'Pamonha', 5.4)
```

- O usuário visualiza o cardápio(o formato tem que sair como na foto)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- o usuário digita qual item ele quer comprar.
  *A seguir pergunta-se se ele quer algo a mais, caso ele queira, vai somando todos os valores do pedido numa variável `soma`.
- No final, printe para o usuário o valor total da conta dele.

```
pontos = ('-'*30)
print(pontos)
print('-'*10,'CARDÁPIO','-'*10)
print(pontos)

for i in range(len(t1)):
 print(t1[i])
print()

carrinho = input("Digite a sua escolha do cardápio: ")
mais_itens = input("Você quer continuar a adicionar mais itens? (s/n): ")

soma = 0

while mais_itens == 's':

 carrinho = input("Digite a sua escolha do cardápio: ")
 mais_itens = input("Você quer continuar a adicionar mais itens? (s/n): ")


 if carrinho == 'Doce':
   soma = t1[1]
   
 elif carrinho == 'Bala':
   soma = t1[3]
   
 elif carrinho == 'Pizza':
   soma = t1[5]
   
 elif carrinho == 'Arroz':
   soma = t1[7]
   
 elif carrinho == 'Paçoca':
   soma = t1[9]
   
 elif carrinho == 'Pamonha':
     soma = t1[11]

print('O valor total da sua conta é: R${}.'.format(soma))
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Interar a tupla usando while ??... O propósito é apresentar a lista de compra com nome preso e ao escolher adicionar a um pseudo carrinho fazendo a soma dos produtos??

Comment: então @stack.cardoso primeiro imprime o cardápio no modelo da foto, e depois o usuário digita o que quer comprar.. e independente do que ele digitou e se continuou a comprar ou não a informação de valor vai pra variável soma. Vou atualizar o código que fiz ali em cima.. o que não estou conseguindo, é como colocar os valores float da tupla.. dentro da variável soma.. pra printar no final..

Answer (score -4, accepted):

É que você tá determinando um novo valor pra variável soma a cada decisão do usuário ao invés de somar. Quando se usa só o "=", atribui-se um novo valor à variável. Nesse caso, como você quer somar um valor a ela, precisa usar "+=", que soma um valor a uma variável

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não use esse espaço para fazer comentários. O tema do site é perguntas e respostas técnicas sobre linguagens de programação, ou seja o site é um Q&A e não deve ser usado como rede social, fórum ou grupo de discussão. O espaço de respostas dever ser usado para fornecer soluções claras e focadas na pergunta feita na página e nos problemas que a acompanham e não apenas uma orientação superficial, pois se olhar com atenção o código da pergunta serão encontrados outros problemas. Essa sua [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/544288/137387) apresenta o mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu respondi a dúvida da pessoa. A dúvida era sobre como armazenar a soma dos valores das comidas escolhidas pelo usuário(pelo menos de acordo com o título da pergunta) e foi justamente isso que eu expliquei

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = ('Doce', 2.3, 'Bala ', 0.15, 'Pizza ', 28.9, 'Arroz ', 4.5, 'Paçoca ', 0.5, 'Pamonha', 5.4)
print('-'*30)
print(f'{"Cardápio":^30}')
print('-'*30)
for pos in range(0,len(t1)):
  if pos % 2 == 0:
    print(f'{t1[pos]:.<20}', end='')
  else:
    print(f'R${t1[pos]:>6.2f}')
print('-'*30)

soma = 0
i = 0
mais = 's'

while mais == 's':

  carrinho = input("Digite a sua escolha do cardápio: ")
 
  if carrinho == 'Doce':
    i = t1[1]
   
  elif carrinho == 'Bala':
    i = t1[3]
   
  elif carrinho == 'Pizza':
    i = t1[5]
   
  elif carrinho == 'Arroz':
    i = t1[7]
   
  elif carrinho == 'Paçoca':
    i = t1[9]
   
  elif carrinho == 'Pamonha':
    i = t1[11]  

  soma = soma + i
  mais = input("Você quer continuar a adicionar mais itens? (s/n): ")

print('O valor total da sua conta é: R${}.'.format(soma))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi desta maneira usando while, e dentro dele peguei a posição do valor digitado + 1 para somar os valores no i.

```
t1 = ('Doce', 2.3, 'Bala', 0.15, 'Pizza', 28.9, 'Arroz', 4.5, 'Paçoca', 0.5, 'Pamonha', 5.4)

## Imprimindo as linhas e textos para deixar a apresentação mais amigavel
print ('-'*39)
print ('-'*15 + ' Cardápio ' + '-'*14)
print ('-'*39)

## O for nesse caso conta até o tamanho do t1(Da Tupla) e se i for divisivel ele imprimi Comidas e não pula linha senão 
## ele imprimi os valor na frente, quando ele chegar no tamanho da t1 ele sai do for
for i in range(0,len(t1)):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    print(f'{t1[i]:.<30}', end='')
  else:
    print(f'R${t1[i]:>7.2f}')
print('-'*39)

## Declaração da variavel comprar
comprar = 'Sim'
i=0

## Enquanto comprar for diferente de Não ele vai continuar a solicitar itens pro pedido
while comprar == 'Sim':
  comprar = input('Quer comprar algum item? ')
  if comprar == ('Sim'):
    itemComprar = input('Qual item que comprar? ')
    pos = int(t1.index(itemComprar)+1)
    pos1 = t1[pos]
    i = i + pos1
print(' ')    
print(f'Total do seu pedido é R$: {i:.2f}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, eu fiz assim, deu certo, tem que declarar uma variável(i) que adiciona na soma:

t1 = ('Doce', 2.3, 'Bala', 0.15, 'Pizza', 28.9, 'Arroz', 4.5, 'Paçoca', 0.5, 'Pamonha', 5.4)
print('-'*28)
print('--------- Cardápio ---------')
print (' 1 - {}............. : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[0],t1[1]))
print (' 2 - {}............. : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[2],t1[3]))
print (' 3 - {}............ : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[4],t1[5]))
print (' 4 - {}............ : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[6],t1[7]))
print (' 5 - {}........... : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[8],t1[9]))
print (' 6 - {}.......... : R$ {:.2f}'.format(t1[10],t1[11]))
print('-'*28)
print('-'*28)

i = 0
soma = 0
mais = 's'
qnt = 0

carrinho = input("Digite a sua escolha do cardápio: ")
qnt = int(input('Quantos desse intem?: '))

while mais == 's':

if carrinho == 'Doce':
i = t1[1]*qnt
elif carrinho == 'Bala':
i = t1[3]*qnt
elif carrinho == 'Pizza':
i = t1[5]*qnt
elif carrinho == 'Arroz':
i = t1[7]*qnt
elif carrinho == 'Paçoca':
i = t1[9]*qnt
elif carrinho == 'Pamonha':
i = t1[11]*qnt

soma += i

mais = input('Deseja pedir mais alguma coisa? (s/n): ')
if mais == 'n':
break

carrinho = input("Escolha outra coisa do cardápio: ")
qnt = int(input('Quantos desse intem?: '))

print('Total do pedido  = R$ {:.2f}'.format(soma))